# Workflow para reverter alterações do branch dev para o master

Tags: git

- O branch `dev` é automaticamente mergeado ao `master`; esse, por sua
  vez, tem um *deploy* automático da aplicação.
- O branch `dev` possui algumas alterações à frente do branch `master` 
  e que serão descartadas.
- O branch `feature` incorretamente saiu do *workflow* e foi criado à
  partir do `master`.

O que preciso fazer é:

1. Excluir as alterações do `dev` e deixá-lo conforme o master

   2. Mergear o `feature` em `dev`

Pensei em "resetar" o `dev`, apagando-o e criando-o a partir do `master`mas não sei se essa é a solução para esses casos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

@edit

Após efetuar o `reset`, `commit` e `push` eu recebo o seguinte erro pois meu branch `dev` possui alterações salvas no `remote`.

> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is
>   behind
>
> hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>
> hint: See the 'Noteabout fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Há código no "dev" e/ou "features" que precise ser aproveitado?

Comment: O código no branch `features` deverá permanecer, @Sergio

Comment: Se só queres "voltar atráz" com o features podias fazer `git reset --hard master` quando estiveres no branch `dev` e fazendo um `git fetch master`  caso seja remoto para estar atualizado em memória. Assim apagas os commits do `dev` que fica igual ao master, e o `features` fica 2 commits à frente do `dev` e do `master`.

Comment: O código em dev é realmente descartável? da pra fazer também um `rebase` na `feature` em `dev` assim você não perde nada.

Comment: Sim, os commits do `dev` à frente ao `master` são descartáveis. @gmsantos

Comment: @Sergio, editei a questão com um detalhe esquecido sobre o branch `dev`

Comment: o seu repositório central é bare?

Comment: Não, @zwitterion

Comment: Foi o que eu imaginei. POr isso vc está tendo essas mensagns de erro quando tenta fazer o update entre os ambientes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que sugiro nesse caso:

**1: Resetar o branch dev para o estado do master.** Veja na [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) a diferença das flags `--soft`, `--mixed` (default) e `--hard`.

```
git reset master
```

**2: Criar um Stash de backup com essas alterações que ocorreram nesses commits revertidos, que agora estão no seu working copy**

```
git stash
```

Como alternativa ao stash, você pode criar um feature branch no ponto do commit C6, revertendo somente o marcador do branch dev. Não tem problema esse branch ficar "desintegrado" do master.

**3: Forçar um merge do branch feature pra dentro do branch dev**

```
git merge feature --no-ff
```

A flag `--no-ff` vai evitar o merge fast-forward, e forçar um commit de "merge" entre os dois branches. Como vocês tem um workflow de desenvolvimento/release um pouco estruturado, é recomendável nesse caso, para manter o histórico de merges. A mesma preocupação vale pra rebases.

**4: Após esse processo, quando for fazer o push do branch dev, você deverá fazer de maneira forçada, já que vai remover commits do origin.**

```
git push -f origin dev
```

É importante que esse processo seja comunicado com toda a equipe, que pode ter seus branches baseados em commits que serão perdidos

Comment: O _stash_ após o `reset` mesmo?

Comment: Se não me engano, o reset default não é no modo hard, e mantém as alterações dos commits na sua working copy, por isso pode fazer o stash depois

Comment: Entendido, porém vi agora que tenho mais um problema e adicionarei na pergunta: Meu branch `dev` possui as alterações salvas no remoto, quando dou o `commit` e `push` ele é rejeitado.

Comment: Faça um rebase do seu master em cima de origin/master

Comment: O `master` e `origin/master` estão ok, @Everton. O problema ocorre somente no `dev`

Comment: Ah sim, nesse caso você deve fazer um push forçado, usando a flag -f

Comment: Resposta atualizada :) é importante que sempre que você venha a fazer um push forçado, que isso seja comunicado à equipe.

Comment: Entendido, a equipe está ciente dos procedimentos discutidos aqui.